# Django | Get an ordered dict from query with relationship

Tags: python, django

I have a working (but ugly) method in a model:

```py
@classmethod
def get_tasks(cls, user):
    tasks = cls.objects\
        .filter(agent=user)\
        .prefetch_related('parent', 'agent')
    ordered_tasks = {}
    for task in tasks:
        if task.parent.pk not in ordered_tasks:
            ordered_tasks[task.parent.pk] = {
                'parent': task.parent,
                'tasks': []
            }
        ordered_tasks[task.parent.pk]['tasks'].append(task)
    return ordered_tasks
```

It work as well, but I'm sure there is a better solution to have the same result.

Any idea for steer me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the dict's [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method:

```
ordered_tasks = {}
for task in tasks:
    ordered_tasks.setdefault(task.parent.pk, {'parent': task.parent,
                                              'tasks': []}
                            )['tasks'].append(task)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, prettier than my condition ;)

No solution to have this result only with django's ORM ?